# How to schedule automatic data refresh on quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

Is there a way to schedule automatic (periodic) data refresh on AWS Quicksight?

Answer (score 1):

As of 21st February it is now possible to schedule SPICE data to refresh, you can configure it directly from your dataset. Have a look at [Refreshing a DataSet on a Schedule in the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/refreshing-imported-data.html#schedule-data-refresh).

[image: Schedule Refresh]

Answer (score 0):

i think you just need to come out of analysis and go back it will refresh to latest.

Answer (score 0):

As at now, scheduled refresh is yet to be available in QuickSight but it's in the pipeline, you can use tools like [Datablade](http://datablade.io/aws) to manage schedules into QuickSight.